# Too many automatic redirects have been attempted in WebClient

Tags: c#

I need to allow redirection in my `WebClient` 'cause I've this url:

```
http://int.soccerway.com/national/algeria/ligue-2/c207/
```

when I add this in the browser I'll get a redirect to this:

```
http://int.soccerway.com/national/algeria/ligue-2/20172018/regular-season/r43168/
```

when I perform a request I execute this method:

```
    public static string GetData(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        try
        {
            webReq.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            webReq.Method = "GET";
            webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            webReq.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;

            using (WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
      ...
   }
```

but this throws an exception:

> Too many automatic redirects have been attempted

other threads suggest to add a cookie container, I did so but the error happen occurs again. How can I solve this?

Comment: `webReq.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;`... So, if the website redirects you twice just kill the request? Why don't you look at Chrome`s Network tab to see how many actual redirects are happening?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the redirect is just one

Comment: You are obviously getting at least another one, otherwise the exception shouldn't occur. Set it to `= 10` or something like that, just for testing.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto ok I've increased the number and now the exception isn't displayed, anyway, I get the reader read to end empty..

Comment: I'd suggest you to try with the `HttpClient` class, it's a wrap of `HttpWebRequest/Response` that makes things like this easier